# Textview show partial text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a textview in which I must load a message. I want to set number of variable is display in textview and after that left message replace with add three dots (...). How can I detect set number of variable is display and after that display three dots(..)

My code for textview is

```
<TextView
        a:id="@+id/tv_message"           
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"          
        a:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />
```

Comment: what u mean by : set number of variable is display?

Comment: yes , if i set number of variable 5 then display only 5 variable of message and display three dots(...) after it . These dots indicate user that some information are not displayed.

Comment: u should use `textview.setText(( textview.getText()).toString().substring(0, 'ur variable')+"...");`

Comment: good but there is no way to do this in xml file.

Comment: u cant do anythng dynamically in xml file

Comment: yes i know it very well , it want to know that there is any inbuild property of textview for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In text view you should work with  [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_ellipsize) property in xml.... Though you need some workaround in Java to make it variable......